# How can I determine a cmd.exe's parent process

Tags: windows, terminal, command-line

Sometimes I find myself in a **cmd.exe** environment that itself was started by another **cmd.exe** or by another console-based application. Now, working in such an environment, I'd like to know what happens if I type `exit`, that is, if the cmd.exe window will disappear, or if it goes back to the **cmd.exe** or application that invoked it. This, of course, because sometimes as I work in **cmd.exe** I forget about how I called it.

So, is there a way to find out the parent process (if this is the correct term) of a **cmd.exe** within another **cmd.exe**?

Comment: "parent process" is correct terminology, but i don't think "terminus" is...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use WMI to get this information. The `Win32_Process` class contains `ParentProcessId`

So (using PowerShell to execute WMI commands—other WMI tools are available):

```
gwmi Win32_Process -filter 'processid = 1234' | select ParentProcessId
```

will give the parent process id of process 1234.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but this sounds correct. Upvoted.

Comment: `(gwmi win32_process | ? processid -eq $pid).parentprocessid` ($pid contains the current process id)

Comment: @LukeSampson Why get all processes and then filter when WMI can do the filtering for you at source? (Ie. use the variable in the `-filter` parameter of  `Get-WmiObject` (`gwmi`) rather than a separate `Where-Object` (`?`).)

Comment: @Richard because I'm lazy and don't want to learn about a special parameter? Anyway thanks for your answer, it helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't from within cmd.exe itself but [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) has a tree view which shows parent processes.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is certainly correct, but I hoped there would be some command or something that I could type into cmd.exe.

Comment: another SysInternals tool, *pslist.exe*, can also provide a tree view.  unfortunately PPID (parent process ID) is not part of the general output, but if the *cmd* window was started by another application the tree view should show that relationship.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Determine the process ID (pid) of the process you are curious about
(i.e., the `cmd.exe` process)
and type

```
wmic process where (ProcessId=<processID>) get Caption,ProcessId,ParentProcessID
```

This gets the same information (by, basically, the same mechanism)
as [Richard's answer](https://superuser.com/a/120501/150988), but using only `cmd` (i.e., not requiring PowerShell).

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a litle more?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the question closely, the OP asks

> So, is there a way to find out the parent process (if this is the
> correct term) of a cmd.exe within another cmd.exe?

This is different from the title, which should probably should have read "How can I determine my current cmd.exe's parent process"

Answering the question not the title, a very simple approach is to use AUTORUN.CMD. Since this run before every invocation of CMD, it can be as simple as:

```
SET /A LEVEL=%LEVEL+1
ECHO LEVEL = %LEVEL%
```

**Caution** AUTORUN.CMD, while it works as documented, it is defined per user and so is really only useful for non-critical things. Any other code which relies on AUTORUN.CMD, must handle the case where it does not exist.

For example, I use AUTORUN.CMD to append a star to the prompt, for each cmd nesting level:

```
PROMPT=%PROMPT%*$S
```

This is seen below.

Since CMD variables are local to the instance, when you exit cmd, the environment values from the "outer" cmd instance are used as can be seen here:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1826]
> (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
> level = 1
> T:\ * cmd
> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1826]
> (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
> level = 2
> T:\ * * exit
> T:\ * echo %LEVEL%
> 1
> T:\ *