# batch programming: initiating program

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

Let's say you have a batch script "main_batch.bat" that will be called/started by a number of different programs like "batch1.bat", "batch2.bat", "program1.exe", "python1.py", etc. Is there a way for "main_batch.bat" to know its initiating/"referer" program/script (ie which program called/started it)?

Comment: The simplest method would be to add a parameter.

Comment: You would probably need to find out your own process ID, and then [find out the parent process ID via WMI](https://superuser.com/questions/120487/how-can-i-determine-a-cmd-exes-parent-process) (note that the example there is for Powershell rather than `cmd` batch files)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

in batch1.bat batch2.bat etc call main_batch.bat with filename (%~nx0) as first parameter

```
main_batch.bat %~nx0
```

in main_batch.bat %1 is the calling batchname

```
echo %1 called main_batch.bat
```

let me know if you need more info